# Sandbox: Is possible to simulate a failed or interrupted In App Purchase?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have recently implemented In App Purchasing in my app. Good thing Apple has [documented the whole process](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html) very well.

Using those docs, I'm finally able to test In App Purchasing through the Sandbox, which is a very convenient feature. I have successfully tested my app so that it reacts to whatever the `StoreKit` returns when I tap the `buyButton`.

Now here's my question. From the docs, it says that the Sandbox simulates the transaction process with no financial stuff. So I'm free to buy as much as I want (by the way, I'm buying consumables and only consumables). Also, the Sandbox will **ALWAYS** simulate a successful transaction, no matter what. So, is it possible to have the Sandbox simulate a **failed** transaction, and better yet, an **interrupted** transaction?

I want to do that to trap possible errors when those events happen (although I've read somewhere that `StoreKit` already handles that) and display them on the screen (at the very least), just to inform the user what's happening during the transaction process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you end up accomplishing this - especially the interrupted transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to simulate lots of common networked transaction problems is to unplug the network cable from the back side of the wifi access point being used at various points in the process.  You could try stuff like unplugging the wifi's WAN cable, then use alternate or cabled access to remove your IAP from availability in iTunes Connect, then re-enable wifi access.

Comment: I'm using shared WI-Fi (office) and I can't really turn it off at will since, well, it's shared.

Comment: You could get another cheap wifi access point, or share the connection from your Mac.

Comment: What about if you are testing on a device with Wifi AND 4G - how can you turn off ALL internet access mid-process, especially when a purchase happens so quickly? And is there no way to test interruptions such as leaving the app altogether to verify a credit card?

Answer (score 1):

iOS 14+.

> You can test interrupted purchase scenarios on a device running iOS 14 or later by enabling interrupted purchases in App Store Connect for a specific tester Sandbox Apple ID. If this option is selected, on-device purchase attempts by that Sandbox Apple ID will be interrupted in the sandbox environment and continue to be interrupted until the option is deselected. This allows you to test your app’s handling of an interruption to ensure a seamless customer experience.

From documentation: [Testing interrupted purchases](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7e89e149d)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to simulate various networked situations is with the Network Link Conditioner utility. It is event mentioned in [Apple documentation regarding networked operation testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WhyNetworkingIsHard/WhyNetworkingIsHard.html).

That way you are not dependant from shared access points, or your co-workers interfering with your tests. You also can easily simulate a lot more situations than just connected/not connected.

[Here is a step-by-step on how to install it and use](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) it on both OSX (for testing in simulator) and iOS.